# Does one App have only one SHA-1 Key even when you share it?

Tags: flutter, dart, sha1

When I program an app with Flutter and then use the SHA-1 key for the Google Maps application. Does it then also work for everyone else or is the SHA-1 key not always the same for the same app but different devices? (Even when I send the Projekt to a friend of mine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SHA-1 fingerprint is usually generated using the java certificate key store (either default or custom as per your decision). if you are generating an APK and sharing the same between your friends, the SHA-1 key will remain the same, but if you are distributing the source code and generating the apk on your friends machine, chances are it is  going to be different

Comment: If I now launch the app will all app users have the same SHA-1 key?

Comment: if you are launching app published to google play or via apk and you used the same certificate, then they will

Comment: How do I do that? Is it by default or do I have to do something spezial? @Vilsad P P

Comment: you don't have to do anything special, just keep the certificate you used to generate SHA-1 fingerprint with you, and use the same while building the app.